# restrict video call access for only host and guest

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

i want to integrate agora on my website with angular.
I need to have several active video calls, how do i make sure that the host and the guest are the only ones joining the session?
And that the rest (host and owner) enter their respective unique rooms? Is there a unique id of temporary channel so that both enter through that or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decide a pre-defined unique channel name which won't be shared with anyone by the host other than the guest.

Check the Agora Documentation for Video Calls [here](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web/index.html).

```html
<label for="form-channel">Meeting ID</label>
<input type="text" id="form-channel" class="form-control" placeholder="Meeting ID" required>

<script>
// Join Channel Modal
$("#join-channel").click(function (event) {
    var agoraAppId = "<APP-ID>";
    var channelName = $('#form-channel').val();
    initClientAndJoinChannel(agoraAppId, channelName);
    $("#modalForm").modal("hide");
});
</script>
```

Using the above code snippet you can make dynamic channels on the go. You can also have predefined channel names coming from a server if you need by giving a variable instead of `$('#form-channel').val();`.

If you still have doubts you can check my sample app at: https://github.com/akshatvg/speakOut. Even though the app isn't on Angular, you will understand how you need to make the channels work.

Comment: thanks, it was exactly what i was looking for. i will make sure to create unique channels